# Angular Material Clipboard begincopy() doesn't work for longer text/JSON

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have used the [Angular Material Clipboard](https://material.angular.io/cdk/clipboard/overview) begincopy() for copying text in my code like below and it works for shorter text/JSON and fails without giving any error for larger text/JSON.

```
import {Clipboard} from '@angular/cdk/clipboard';

class HeroProfile {
  lifetimeAchievements: JSON[]; //some large JSON around 15MB

  constructor(private clipboard: Clipboard) {}

  copyAchievements() {
    const pending = this.clipboard.beginCopy(JSON.stringify(this.lifetimeAchievements,null, 1));
    let remainingAttempts = 3;
    const attempt = () => {
      const result = pending.copy();
      if (!result && --remainingAttempts) {
        setTimeout(attempt);
      } else {
        // Remember to destroy when you're done!
        pending.destroy();
      }
    };
    attempt();
  }
}
```

[Demo Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-clipboard-demo-aogqte?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)